# Manhwa where the female lead keeps repeating the day when her brother kills her

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

In this manhwa, the (blonde?) female lead is a princess and lives alone in her palace. She has various brothers; one has long (white or green) hair and has the power to use plants.

Another one of her brothers, a black haired tyrant, one day kills her because she can't properly answer his questions. She reincarnates the day prior, but gets killed once again.

This happens over and over until she pretends to like her big brother very much and he spares her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Answer (score 3):

This is *[Don't Concern Yourself With That Book](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/dont-concern-yourself-with-that-book)*.

> I was reborn as Ashley Rosé, the daughter of the 8th wife of the Emperor of Estria. ... Ashley Rosé was destined to die by the hands of the Crown Prince, Castor the Tyrant! “What does the empire mean to you?”, the Crown Prince asked, smiling oh so very beautifully. And then he killed me. **After my death, I woke up once again in the past, only to be killed over and over again**. As I continued to relive my deaths, I slowly lost my smile and changed. Let’s just try to survive first. “What can I do for my elder brother?”

The main character reincarnates as a blonde princess that lives alone in her palace. She has two brothers that appear in the story; a black haired prince that kills her for not answering questions to his satisfaction,

[image: black haired tyrant kills the main character]

and a sickly man with light blue hair that is surrounded by plants. Presumably he has the ability to manipulate them in some way, but this isn't explicitly shown in the first two chapters.

[image: Other brother, surrounded by plants]

The main character finds a book that tells the future, particularly of the black haired prince's plan to kill her.

Comment: I read this a while ago and can't recall if she ever actually dies after the story starts, or if it's entirely predictions from the book. It's tagged as a time loop story, so I'm guessing it's both.